# Deploying code first code migrations based web app to server, but it's not creating the database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have my own box so I have complete control over the server. I'm using SQL server 2008. I run the application hoping it will create the database, but I keep getting the error:

> Cannot open database "blah blah" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\appname'.

I've tried to go into SSMS and add the user IISAPPPOOL\appname but that hasn't helped any. Here's the connection string from my web.config

```
<add name="Context" 
     connectionString="Data Source=Server\DbInstance;Initial Catalog=blahblah;Integrated Security=True;User ID=myUser;Password=myPassword" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and the initializer from my global.asax

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Context, Configuration>());
```

Is the app failing because code first is failing and not creating the database or is it because of permissions issues? If I need to provide more specific information I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one problem you have: you're defining **both** `Integrated Security=True` (i.e. Windows authentication) as well as `User ID=...;Password=....` (i.e. SQL Server authentication) in your connection string.

Choose one or the other - but not both at the same time!

If you do have that user `myUser` specified as a login in your SQL Server, right now, it will not be used, because the `Integrated Security=True` setting will prevail ...

So change your connection string to:

```
<add name="Context" 
     connectionString="Data Source=Server\DbInstance;Initial Catalog=blahblah;User ID=myUser;Password=myPassword" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and see if now, you're `myUser` user will be used.

Comment: Thanks man I'm gonna try this on Monday. I'm seriously clueless when it comes to sql server or any database for that matter so I definitely need to brush up on that.